# Clicking link in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have an anchor tag on all my pages:

```
<a id='signout' href='//somelocation'>SignOut</a>
```

and I have a JavaScript file that is available to all pages. There is a function that is called and attached to 'click' , 'touch' and 'key press' handler where I am trying to click the link. Something like:

```
document.addEventListener('click' function(e){
   var signoff = document.getElementById('signout');
   location = signoff.href;  
}
```

This should just click the anchor tag whenever there is a click event but is not working.

Comment: I'm guessing right now you're ending up at `//somelocation` ?

Comment: .. what? You want to click the anchor that has been clicked by the user?

Answer (score 1):

Some syntax corrections got it working for me:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   var signoff = document.getElementById('signout');
   location = signoff.href;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jjGeJ/